# If $A \cap B = C \cap D$ and $E = C \cup D$ and $D \subset B$, then $A \subset C $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i came across an abstract algebra set theory problem, and i am wishing some **hints**

let A, B, C, D be subsets of set E
show that if

**$A \cap B = C \cap D, E = C \cup D, D \subset B$, THEN $A \subset C $**

Comment: Yeah, this is not abstract algebra, this is elementary set theory. Please do read the tag descriptions before using them.

Comment: Hint: Pick an element $a\in A$. You want to show it is also in $C$. If it is in $B$, then `blah`. if it is not in $B$, then it is not in $D$; but since it is in $E$, then `blah`.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in A$, if $a\in B$ then $a\in A\cap B$ so?

Otherwise, if $a\not \in B$, then $a\in B^c \subset D^c$, so ??

Comment: thank you, but I asked for a hint not a full answer